# Можно ли сделать проще и вообще нужно ли

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Есть таблица и ее стоблцы отображаются по пришедшему `id`. Вопрос, я чувствую что можно это сделавть лучше чем я сделал сейчас, но как? Как вариант, записать в массив и отображать по пришедшему `id`?

```
  for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    switch (id) {
      case 0:
        tax[i].style.display = "block";
        tax[i].style.display = "none";
        tax[i].style.display = "none";
        break;
      case 1:
        tax[i].style.display = "none";
        tax[i].style.display = "block";
        tax[i].style.display = "none";
        break;
      case 2:
        tax[i].style.display = "none";
        tax[i].style.display = "none";
        tax[i].style.display = "block";
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: зачем по три присвоения в каждом `case`? Сработает только последнее.

Comment: Опишите цель кода. Опишите что именно по вашему должно быть "лучше" - скорость, компактность, еще что-то? Прочитайте описание метки [инспекция-кода]. И дайте плиз вопросу нормальное название отражающее суть

Comment: Этот код вообще рабочий? Приведи воспроизводимый пример,о том что должен делать этот код можно строить только догадки.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d1 = (id == 0)? "block" : "none";
var d2 = (id == 1)? "block" : "none";
var d3 = (id == 2)? "block" : "none";

for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
  // c этими тремя строчками что-то не так, но воспроизведем как в вопросе
  tax[i].style.display = d1;
  tax[i].style.display = d2;
  tax[i].style.display = d3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const map1 = ['block', 'none', 'none']
const map2 = ['none', 'block', 'none']
const map3 = ['none', 'none', 'block']

table.forEach((row, i) => {
   tax[i].style.display = map1[id]
   tax[i].style.display = map2[id]
   tax[i].style.display = map3[id]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае можно просто индекс с id сравнивать:

```
for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    tax[i].style.display = i === id ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```